# Linking html frontend and python backend integration

Tags: python, html, integration

I wanted to integrate my frontend code with my python backend functionality

This is my frontend code with html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Subtitle AI</title>
    ...
</head>

<body>

    <div class="upload">
        <h3>Step 1: upload a .wav file</h3>
        <input id="wavFile" type="file" name="myFile" accept=".wav" />
        <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <h3>Step 2: Wait for model to generate closed captioning</h3>
    <p id="result"></p>

    <script>
        $("#submit-button").click(function(event) {
            let parameter1 = {
                return1: $("#wavFile").val(),
            };
            $.post(
                "http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict",
                JSON.stringify(parameter1),
                function(transcription) {
                    $("#result").text(transcription.result);
                    console.log(transcription);
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my pytohn backend code functionality + attempted integration. I tried to integrate it with Flask, not sure what went wrong, but when I clicked the button, the return value from my python backend function is not displaying.

```
...
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])

...

# define the prediction function which takes in the file path to a wav file and outputs the predicted words

def predict (model, device, path): 

    
    ...

    # decode the IDs to text
    transcription = processor.decode(predicted_ids[0])
    return jsonify(transcription)
```

Comment: cound't  find  jquery  reference in the html , did you got any error in browser console?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  add it in html head session

Comment: check your bowser network tab(in  inspect ) for the request is happening, if its happening whats the result, response status,  check whether its , 200.  if you get 400, there is some issue with the data send to the server, if its 500 , issue in the server side code.

Comment: I added the script src and I have another error from the console - Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) and [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-input-element)  tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.